# Increment with Find -exec

Tags: linux, bash, find, increment

I'm doing a script with find today in which I'm (essentially) trying to find pngs, and then use tesseract on them and name the output with a serial number.  I'm attempting to do this as below.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
find /home/mine/Pictures -iname "*.png" -exec tesseract {} /home/mine/Temporary/test/$count \; -exec bash -c count=$((count+1)) \;
```

Tesseract works just fine within this context but I can't get my counting variable to increment and so it just stays at zero.  Can anyone help me out?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`-exec` will run this bash command in a new bash process multiple times.  Bash variables only have scope within the bash process to which they belong.  So every time `-exec` starts up another bash, $count will restart at 0.

I assume you are simply trying to count the number of files processed.  I think your could do this instead:

```
find /home/mine/Pictures -iname "*.png" -exec tesseract {} /home/mine/Temporary/test/$count -print | wc -l
```

This should print out each filename found on a new line.  This output is piped to the `wc -l` command which simply counts the number of lines, i.e. the number of files processed.

The caveat is that if your filenames contain newlines, then they may take up more than one line each.  But who puts newline characters in their filenames? ;-)